# What keyboard shortcuts are available in Code?

Tags: code

What keyboard shortcuts are available for actions like manipulating files and directories / projects, manipulating code / text, showing / hiding features, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The ones I could find so far:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> / <kbd>O</kbd> / <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd> / <kbd>W</kbd> / <kbd>Q</kbd> All do the same as in every other app

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> Comment the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Go to line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Open new blank tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> Also open new blank tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> Search and replace
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Also search and replace
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Duplicate line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> Insert emoticon
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> Toggle sidebar
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Open last-closed tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> Save as
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Switch between code and the terminal (when open)

Answer (score 0):

I find it quite annoying that there's no easy way of finding these. Whats the point?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Seems to comment a line.